# Minimum wage in the Solow-Swan model

Tags: macroeconomics, solow, minimum-wage

We introduce a minimum wage level such that the real wage may not be
lower than this minimum. So, what is the effect of this policy for capital accumulation, saving rate and so on in the Solow-Swan model??

Comment: Hi, we have a policy where user has to demonstrate some minimum amount of effort by showing us the attempt to solve the problem before other users attempt to provide solution for homework/self study questions

Comment: My attempt was: looking the golden rule k in which we observe the max wage, if this minimum is greater than the max wage than no analysis; instead, for a value less than max wage (given a k0 start), something could happen. From Acemoglu, the economy would collapse in the LR given investment reduce over time and k goes to zero. This is my issue. @1muflon1

Comment: then please show us that attempt add the calculations you attempted to your question. Use mathajx (if you are familiar with LaTex it’s virtually the same thing) so if you want to write $y=ax+b$ write ‘$y=ax+b$’. Also move the explanation from the comment to your question you can edit your original question

Comment: I do not have calculations, I do not know how to proceed, that's why I'm asking for help dude, or no? Then, the fundamental relationships of the model are always the same but I don't understand how they react to the introduction of the policy. if you don't want to help me don't worry. @1muflon1

Comment: I want to help you but on this site we have rules that before we attempt to provide help you have to try it on your own and show us the calculations the calculations don’t need to be correct just show us the attempt. If you are not willing to do that then this question will likely be closed. These are our community rules. You can see more details about them in the help center at the bottom of the page